# How to get the value of one input field in a "v-for" of multiple inputs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have multiple text inputs generated in v-for directive which i have attached to one v-model variable as show below. I have a button by the respective inputs which prints the value of the current working input. Ultimately I want to extract value of the selected input without affecting the other inputs.

But apparent any change make in one input affect all the input. I super confused as to how I will achieve this. Any help will be much appreciated.

My attempted code is shown below.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="i in 5" :key="i">
      <input v-model="text" type="text" :key="i" />
      <button @click="printText">print</button> <span>{{ text }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    printText() {
      console.log(this.text);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: make `text` an array and then do `v-model="text[i]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an array instead of simple variable when you use v-model in v-for

And on click pass the index with function call

Try to use

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="i in 5" :key="i">
      <input v-model="text[i]" type="text"/>
      <button @click="printText(i)">print</button> <span>{{ text[i] }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    printText(index) {
      console.log(this.text[index]);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```